# SimpleDHT: what does error code 4112 mean? (not in source code on GitHub)

Tags: sensor, esp8266

I am using the [SimpleDHT](https://github.com/winlinvip/SimpleDHT) library, running on a ESP8266.

Occasionally I get error code 4112 on serial output. The variable that holds this error code is declared as an int.

However, the [source code](https://github.com/winlinvip/SimpleDHT/blob/master/SimpleDHT.h) has them in hexadecimal, and none of them appear to be 4112 (0x1010).

Also, the error codes [used to be](https://github.com/winlinvip/SimpleDHT/commit/d9fdf0661f599fa9148b4a403ee9ff5b83746f9f#diff-c2047dd14d6c81c9d6dccfd6c69ea0be) in decimal format in the source code, but the authors have changed it with reason "Combine error and t into error code". Not sure if that is a clue, no idea what 't' refers to.

Comment: The author combines 8 bit "time duration" and 8 bit error code into a 16 bit output. " For example, 0x0310 means t=0x03 and code=0x10 "

Comment: So 4112 in hex is 0x1010 which means t=0x10 and error code is 0x10?

Comment: Did you printf the entire "output"? If so, I'm quite sure it is correct.